# ListView between two TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I got two TextViews and one ListView. I want to put the ListView between the two TextViews. Now when the ListView size grows (I add items dynamically) it should stop growing when the TextView below hits the bottom and become scrollable.

The second TextView should be directly under the ListView at all times.

I almost tried everything that came to my mind but couldn't succeed.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lifo.skipandgo.activities.ShoppingBasketActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:longClickable="false"
                app:logo="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/storeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:text="StoreName" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/storeName">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/basketItemListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:dividerHeight="1px">
            </ListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="Gesamtpreis" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried `LinearLayout` with `weights` ?

Comment: @AbdulKawee Yes, I did. The problem with this was, that the second TextView wasn't directly placed under the ListView anymore. There was some space between them.

Comment: what do u want exactly *there should be space between them from beginning* or *there shouldnt be any space* ?

Comment: @SantanuSur There should be no space at all

Comment: i have added an answer.. just use that method... and pass your listview as argument @progNewbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution myself. Thanks for everyone trying to help me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lifo.skipandgo.activities.ShoppingBasketActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:longClickable="false"
                app:logo="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/storeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:text="StoreName" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/storeName">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/basketItemListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:dividerHeight="1px">
                </ListView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalPrice"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:text="Gesamtpreis" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your xml as it is.. just use this function in your activity..

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(final ListView listView) {
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
        int listWidth = listView.getMeasuredWidth();
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));


            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.d("listItemHeight " + listItem.getMeasuredHeight(), "********");
        }

        Log.d("totalHeight " + totalHeight, "********");

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1)));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have hack for it, you could use two buttons, one will be below the `ListView` and one will stick to bottom of Parent, but make one of them visible at a time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lifo.skipandgo.activities.ShoppingBasketActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:longClickable="false"
                app:logo="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/storeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:text="StoreName" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/storeName">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/basketItemListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:dividerHeight="1px">
            </ListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="Gesamtpreis" />

        </LinearLayout>

               <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalPrice1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="Gesamtpreis" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then whenever you add items in list dynamically, after adding items call below function to check whether your RecyclerView is scrollable or not i.e Scrollbars are visible or not. If this method returns true then make visibility of `totalPrice` as `GONE` and make visibility of `totalPrice1` as `VISIBLE` and vice versa when you delete items from list.

```
public boolean isRecyclerScrollable() {
  LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
  RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
  if (layoutManager == null || adapter == null) return false;

  return layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < adapter.getItemCount() - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to give `android:weightSum="2"` in your parent layout of listview and `android:layout_weight="1"` to your child elements like this below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:longClickable="false"
                app:logo="@drawable/ic_noti"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/storeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:text="StoreName" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/storeName">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/basketItemListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:dividerHeight="1px">
            </ListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Gesamtpreis" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

output..

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried this before myself but the ListView pushes the TextView below out of the screen when there are too many items in it.

Comment: @progNewbie I just updated in your original code..and working nice